# python - " Import error no module named httplib2" in only some files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip, google-api-python-client, httplib2

When I import the httplib2 in quickStart.py and run it using terminal It works.

Now I import quickStart in another file main.py(Google app engine web app python file) and try loading the page via localhost it shows  "Import error no module named httplib2" while both files are in the same directory.
It shows following error :-

```
ERROR    2015-10-13 12:41:47,128 wsgi.py:263]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "G:\dtuwiki\dtuwiki2\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import quickStart
  File "G:\dtuwiki\dtuwiki2\quickStart.py", line 2, in <module>
    import httplib2
ImportError: No module named httplib2
INFO     2015-10-13 18:11:47,398 module.py:809] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

main.py

```
  import webapp2
    import jinja2
    import os 
    import cgi
    import quickStart
    template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')


    root_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    jinja_env = 

jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader([template_dir,root_dir]),autoescape=True)

    def escapeHTML(string):
        return cgi.escape(string , quote="True")


class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self,*a,**kw):
        #self.response.write(form %{"error":error})
        self.response.out.write(*a,**kw)
    def render_str(self,template,**params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)     
    def render(self , template ,**kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template,**kw))
```

quickStart.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

import datetime

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')  
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials
```

I also tried following --

```
$ python -m pip install httplib2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip -V
pip 7.1.2 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip list
google-api-python-client (1.4.2)
httplib2 (0.9.2)
Jinja2 (2.8)
oauth2client (1.5.1)
pip (7.1.2)
uritemplate (0.6)
virtualenv (13.1.2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App Engine requires that any 3rd party modules be included inside the application source tree in order to deploy it to App Engine. This means that items inside `site-packages` will not be imported into an app running under the development SDK and you will see an error similar to what you are experiencing.

[Here are the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring) on how to include libraries like `httplib2`.

The short of it is that you would need to `pip install -t some_dir <libname>` and then add `some_dir` to your application's path inside of `appengine_config.py`